# How can I check if a cell is used in a formula and apply conditional formatting based on the result in Excel?

Tags: excel

How can I check if a cell is argument of a formula somewhere in my worksheet?

I would like to have conditional formatting of cells for cells that are or are not part of a formula.
Visually, one can use "trace dependents", but I would like to use this information in a more systematic way, i.e. to have different formatting based on a cell being or not part of a formula.

I tried to look into formulas, but it did not help.

Comment: You will need to create vba to do this.  Native formula that are used in conditional formatting will not be able to do this.  I was going to suggest you creating a UDF, but that would need to be run for every cell every time the sheet recalculates.  It would slow it down to a crawl every time a change was made.  So writing vba in a sub to check and color the whole sheet would be quicker.